# Python Turn-based Recursion with Lists

Tags: python, list, recursion

I am working on a problem for one of my CS classes and am pretty confident I have the right idea, just when I implement it I don't get the correct answers.

The game is: There are two players, and a list of numbers (i.e. [3,7,8,1,6,4,5]). Each player takes a turn picking a number from either end of the list. Once a number is selected it is removed from the list, and the opponent can then choose from this new list which end they would like to take. The objective is to get the largest sum of numbers by the time the list is empty.

**My thoughts:** Let's say we start off with the simple list [1,2,3,4,5]. When player 1 picks a number from the beginning or end (either 1 or 5), we now have a smaller list to work with that the opponent can choose from. So let me give an example using this list:

I pick 5. The new list is [1,2,3,4] that the opponent can choose from.I don't know which end of the list they will choose, but I know it can only be 1 or 4. If it's 1, then when it is my turn again, I'm left with [2,3,4]. If they pick 4, I'm left with [1,2,3]. If I pick 1, they are left with [2,3], and if I pick 3, they are left with [1,2], etc, until there are no numbers left in the list. The opponent is also trying their best to get the highest score as well, so they won't just greedily pick the greater number all the time. The players are equally intelligent, and so they will both use the exact same strategies to get the highest score for themselves.

This is an obvious recursive problem on a smaller list each time.

**Note:** I'm not looking for code to be given. As it's a cs course, I really would much rather be given hints on what I may be doing wrong so that I can learn rather than be given the code.

This is the code I've written:

```
def Recursive(A):
    # check if there is only one item left. If so, return it 
    if len(A) == 1:
         return A[0]

    # take the left item and recurse on the list if the opponent 
    # were to take the left side, and the list if the opponent 
    # were to take the right number
    takeLeftSide = A[0] + max(Recursive(A[1:-1]), Recursive(A[2:len(A)]))
    takeRightSide = A[-1] + max(Recursive(A[0:-2]), Recursive(A[1:-1]))

    return max(takeLeftSide, takeRightSide)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    A = [5,8,1,3,6]
    print Recursive(A)
```

I believe I should expect 12, but my output is giving me 19 and 14 in some cases.

I appreciate the help, I've been working at this for hours and I know that once you try and dive into recursion stuff just gets messy and confusing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Apparently you don't actually have two players, you're just choosing based on some logic. What is `Recursive()` supposed to return?

Comment: This doesn't look like something for which I would naturally use recursion.

Comment: It returns the maximum sum that one player can get. I wasn't sure how to really add players since I can't add another parameter to the method

Comment: it doesn't need to be recursive, an empty list evaluates to ```False``` in a boolean expression so you could use a ```while``` loop.

Comment: I mean you're not actually creating a game for two people to play, it's just a function to find the maximum score a player can get.

Comment: Do you want the maximum score either player can get, or specifically the first or second player? Do you want the maximum possible score, or the maximum score assuming both players play optimally?

Comment: Edited the post, I am looking for the maximum score assuming both players play optimally. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I tried (using your input). It's almost exactly identical to yours.

```
def r(a):
    if len(a) == 1:
        return a[0]
    takeLeft = a[0] + max(r(a[1:-1]), r(a[2:]))
    takeRight = a[-1] + max(r(a[:-2]), r(a[1:-1]))
    return max(takeLeft, takeRight)
```

The correct answer is 19.

The reason is this: Assuming that we're looking for the highest POSSIBLE score (not the one where both people use optimal strategy), then the game would go as follows:

```
P1: 6          Leftover: [5,8,1,3]
P2: 3          Leftover: [5,8,1]
P1: 6 + 5      Leftover: [8,1]
P2: 3 + 1      Leftover: [8]
P1: 6 + 5 + 8  Leftover: []
```

So P1 has 19 and P2 has 4.

EDIT: HERE IS WHAT HAPPENS IN OPTIMAL SITUATION WHEN USING THE GIVEN (slightly altered) RECURSIVE CODE

```
def r(a):
    if len(a) == 1:
        return a[0]
    if len(a) == 2 or len(a) == 3:
        if a[0] > a[-1]:
            return True
        return False
    takeLeft = a[0] + max(r(a[1:-1]), r(a[2:]))
    takeRight = a[-1] + max(r(a[:-2]), r(a[1:-1]))
    if takeLeft > takeRight:
        return True
    return False

def game(a):
    p1 = 0
    p2 = 0
    p1Turn = True
    while len(a) > 0:
        isLeft = r(a)
        nextValue = -1
        if isLeft: #if it's from the left
            nextValue = a[0]
            a = a[1:]
        else: #if it's from the right
            nextValue = a[-1]
            a = a[:-1]
        if p1Turn:
            p1 += nextValue
        else:
            p2 += nextValue
        p1Turn = not p1Turn
    print "P1:", p1, "P2:", p2
```

Here's how the game plays out in this scenario:

```
P1: 6         Leftover: [5, 8, 1, 3]
P2: 5         Leftover: [8, 1, 3]
P1: 6 + 8     Leftover: [1, 3]
P2: 5 + 3     Leftover: [1]
P1: 6 + 8 + 1 Leftover: []

P1: 15 P2: 8
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, and I've edited my post, as I should have been more clear. In-fact, I am supposed to be looking for the highest score of one player where both players are equally intelligent and using optimal strategies to get the highest score. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Not trying to question your answer, but why when it is P2's first turn, would they choose 5? Wouldn't (in theory) they want to choose 3 as so to not open up the 8 to be chosen by P1? I would have thought that strategy would be taken into account and you want want to take less of your points to prevent the opponent from gaining more. Thoughts?

Comment: You're correct. I guess I was just trying to use his recursive code. Editing my description now.

Comment: P2 would not take 5 on the second move. He would choose 3, then 8.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is returning 19 based on this input, and it should do that. You never actually take the second player's actions into account, and you just assume that second player will take the number which lets player 1 maximise their score. You should use

```
takeLeftSide = A[0] + (sum(A[1:]) - Recursive(A[1:]))
takeRightSide = A[-1] + (sum(A[:-1]) - Recursive(A[:-1]))
```

which is equivalent to

```
takeLeftSide = sum(A) - Recursive(A[1:])
takeRightSide = sum(A) - Recursive(A[:-1])
```

but easier to understand.

What this does is says that a player can get a number from 1 end, and then all the points that the other player doesn't get from the remaining numbers.
If you need more information, or I was unclear, have a look at [the minimax algorithm.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this on the input set of [1,2,3]. I believe the answer to this should be 4, since player 1 could take 3, player 2 takes 2, then player 1 is left with 1, and 3 + 1 = 4, but I am getting 5 returned for this solution. I am trying to read through the minimax algorithm right now, though, so thank you

Comment: Sorry about that, I made a small mistake. The player gets the points from the number that they pick, and then all the points from the REMAINING numbers that the opponent doesn't get. I had accidentally included the value that the player picked twice. I have edited my answer.

Comment: This looks really good. I really appreciate it. I'm going to do some double checking on more lists for the mean time, but thank you so far

Comment: Alright I hate to force you to re-look at this, but I tried another case: [20,1,15,9,19].

P1: 20
P2: 19

P1: 20 + 9 (since regardless of what it takes P2 will get 15)
P2: 19 + 15

P1: 29 + 1

I get an output of 30, when really I believe I should be getting 34, from P2's choices. Does that look correct?

Comment: P1 gets 30 points in that situation, and P2 gets 34 points. At the moment recursive A will tell you the amount of points that P1 gets. If you want to know how many points the second player gets then you can just subtract P1's score from the total number of points.

    `p1_score = Recursive(A);
    p2_score = sum(A) - p1_score;
    print("Player 1 scored %d points, and player 2 scored %d points."%(p1_score, p2_score))`

Answer (score 0):

In order for both players to be "equally intelligent" they should use the same method (algorithm) of choosing a side, each round.

In order to program it, you should develop the algorithm for choosing a side (front of the line or back of it), based on a given list and call this algorithm each time for a different player.

In order to demonstrate it, I chose a relatively primitive greedy algorithm, which always chooses the bigger between the two:

```
def pick_greedy(A):
    if len(A) == 0:
        result = 0
    elif len(A) == 1:
        result = A.pop()
    elif A[0] > A[-1]:
        result = A[0]
        A = A[1:]
    else:
        result = A[-1]
        A = A[:-1] 
    return A, result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    A = [5,8,1,3,6]
    x = 0
    y = 0
    while A:
        A, _ = pick_greedy(A)
        x += _
        A, _ = pick_greedy(A)
        y += _
        print "Player 1: {}; Player 2: {}".format(x, y)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Player 1: 6; Player 2: 5
Player 1: 14; Player 2: 8
Player 1: 15; Player 2: 8
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your current implementation is that Player 1 should get the **min** of the secondary calls, not the max (Player 2 will get the max of those calls). If you make that change, you get the expected result: `12`.

```
takeLeftSide  = A[0]  + min(Recursive(A[1:-1]), Recursive(A[2:len(A)]))
takeRightSide = A[-1] + min(Recursive(A[0:-2]), Recursive(A[1:-1]))
```

Three other problems with your current implementation: (a) very slow as the input list grows in size; (b) raises `IndexError` if the input list has an even number of values; and (c) raises `RuntimeError` if the input list is empty.

**But here's a different way to think about the problem:**

If there are an even number of values in the list, Player 1 can guarantee a win or tie by deciding whether to take all values with **even indexes** or all values with **odd indexes**.

If there are an odd number of values in the initial list, Player 1 simply needs to decide between left vs right. That initial choice then creates an even-sized list situation for Player 2, who will fall back to the strategy noted above.

Thus, Player 1 can predict Player 2's moves and should make the initial left-vs-right choice accordingly.

```
def f(xs):
    evens = sum(xs[i] for i in range(0, len(xs), 2))
    odds  = sum(xs[i] for i in range(1, len(xs), 2))
    if len(xs) % 2 == 0:
        return max(evens, odds)
    else:
        lft = xs[0]
        rgt = xs[-1]
        return max(
            lft + min(odds, evens - lft),
            rgt + min(odds, evens - rgt),
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from random import randint
    tests = [
        (0,     []),
        (5,     [5]),
        (30,    [20, 1, 15, 9, 19]),
        (12,    [5, 8, 1, 3, 6]),
        ('big', [randint(0, 100) for _ in xrange(0, 99999)]),
    ]
    for exp, vals in tests:
        print exp, f(vals)
```

Unlike the recursive implementation, this approach is `O(N)` and thus has the advantage of being able to handle very large lists.